# Cursor moving to the upper right corner

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, xorg, nvidia, troubleshooting

My dad bought a Lenovo Erazer X510 desktop system a little over a year ago. It is Intel based, and has an Nvidia graphics card. Not that it matters because the fault comes even on the integrated Intel.

So far, I have tried almost every posible distro "in town". Fedora and Ubuntu, in different spins and flavours have all been tried. So far, the issue can be reproduced just by using the computer and waiting basically.

The flaw or error occurs, when the cursor suddenly wanders to the top right corner. It has done so with all distros. What I have tried so far:

- The "drain power trick", where you pull out the power cord, and either hold or press repeatedly the power button.
- Tried to blacklist the psmouse driver, since that has been reporting errors on "serio1", where it tries to start the "mouse", and then fails. (Not possible on Fedora)
- On Fedora, tried going around xorg-nouveau, and installing proprietary Nvidia driver
- Tried using different mice and keyboards. One time I had a wired keyboard plugged in and the cursor moved to the corner.

These issues seem to have one thing in common: Lenovo. And since Linux is not officially supported, then Linux users are **** out of luck.

I am left with this:
Either it's hardware related, or the system creates some .files in the home folder than corrupts the mouse.

I am really hoping for somebody to have something to guide me closer to an actual solution(s), since this issue is driving me and my dad up the wall.

I thank you in advance.[image: A possible culprit]

Comment: "Wanders" or "jumps"? A stuck key? Lenovo make good hardware and most of their laptops have good support by the free Unices.

Comment: A key can't be stuck, as I wrote, I have tried with  different mice and keyboards. It even does so when nothing is plugged in.
Also, I work with Thinkpads, but since this is a desktop, I don't see the relevance.

Comment: Ah, I thought it was a laptop (didn't look it up).

Comment: I have added a picture of what I think the possible culprit could be.